# Conditional Formatting to highlight weekends

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to grey out some cells in a table relating to weekends (non-working days).
In Row 2 I have the date and Row 1 use the `=TEXT(A2,"DDD")` to get the day, eg. Sat & Sun

Now I want to have a rule which will select all the columns from rows 3 - 10

[image]

The above works for the row that has the dates in, but I want it to be all the rows below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have the change the type of CF rule to *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*.

Clear the existing rules and select D1:AH10 with D1 as the *active cell*. Use Home ► Conditional Formatting ► New Rule. Choose *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and provide he following for *Format values where this formula is true:*

`=AND(ISNUMBER(D$2),WEEKDAY(D$2,2)>5,ROW()<>2)`

Click `Format` and select your grey fill. Click OK to accept the formatting and OK again to create the new rule. Your results should be similar to teh following.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that did exactly what I wanted. Seems a long-winded way of doing it though? Is there a better way of laying it out?

Comment: @TomC - Your data is pretty straightforward and I don't think I would change its general layout. Personally, I would not change the top row to text, merely use `=D2` and format the cell as *ddd* but I have an aversion to changing any data from a calculable number or date to the textual representation of the same. I would also change the numbers to an accounting style that substitutes hyphens for the zeroes but again, that is a personal preference.